# How to parse JSON NVarChar(max) in SQL Server for Update

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-update

I am trying to both

1. Save a JSON string to a table cell
2. Parse part of the JSON string and set it to its own cell

Using SQL Server

```
 create procedure json_parse_and_update
   @i int,
   @json nvarchar(max)
 as 

update testTable
set 
json_str = @json, -- Save entire JSON string to table cell
json_prop1 = json_value(my_prop,'$.nested.property'), -- Parse JSON and update a single column 
json_prop2 = json_value(my_prop2,'$.nested2.property2')
from @json
where [key] = @i;
```

However, I'm not sure how to select a JSON property from a variable, the examples I see are selecting JSON properties from a table.

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '{
  "nested": {
    "property1": "value",
    "property2": 0
  },
  "nested2": {
    "property1": "value",
    "property2": 0
  }
}'
```

Test table is like

```
json_str | json_prop1       | json_prop_2       |
---------+------------------+-------------------+
json_str | nested_property1 | nested2_property2 |
```

How would I select and update `nested.property` into a column named `json_prop1`?

Comment: *"I'm not sure how to select a JSON property from a variable"* just replace the column's name with the variable's name. It's the same logic that you would use if yo7u wanted to return a variable in a `SELECT` statement instead of a column. `SELECT @MyVarable, MyColumn;`

Comment: Like... `json_prop = (select json_value(my_prop,'$.nested.property') from @json)`?

Comment: Is there going to be more than one property in your json? Show what testtable looks like.

Comment: @dfundako Yes, more than one property. I have updated with an example table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is my_prop?
Try to do like this:

```
json_prop1 = json_value(@json,'$.nested.property')
json_prop2 = json_value(@json,'$.nested2.property2')
```

Comment: you don't need to casting a variable name, you can update the column json_prop1 directly with json_value like I did above.     json_prop1 = json_value(@json,'$.nested.property')